# How to auto load a particular project in mit app inventor rather than the previous project?

Tags: java, app-inventor

I have setup mit app inventor on my local machine. Now I am trying to load a particular project as soon as I land on the mit app inventor projects screen.

Steps I have implemented to achieve this:

1. Disable auto load of previous project from the code for every user.
2. Passing the project ID (of the project that I want to auto load) in the URL.

Now, as far as I understood the codebase then if we return the project ID that I am getting from URL from `getCurrentProjectID` function of `Ode.java` file then the job is done. Thats where the problem start, I am not sure how can I do that.

I am open to any other approach to the main requirement.

Comment: Let me suggest you to ask the specialists in the MIT App Inventor community https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings menu, disable Project Autoload. From now on, each time you log into MIT App Inventor, it will take it to the list of projects. You can choose now which one you want to start.